# Android Studio не видит содержимое папки drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable

Папка изначальная, добавлял изображения разными способами и через программу и через проводник, названия файлов без пробелов и прочего.

```
binding.ivExample.setImageResource(R.drawable.???)
```

изображение не выбирается, когда вручную вписываешь выдает ошибку,
проект пересобрал

Comment: Попробуйте создать другую папку drawable-nodpi просто для эксперимента. Другие ресурсы видит, например mipmap-hdpi?

Comment: Проверьте пакет в импорте класса `R` - он есть не только у вас, но и в каждой библиотеке для Андроида, легко можно перепутать.

Comment: создал папку drawable-nodpi но её не видит андроид

Comment: import android.R   есть но почему то подсвечен цветом

Comment: mipmap-hdpi тоже не видит

Comment: `import android.R` - это ресурсы фреймворка, ваших там нет и быть не может. Ваши ресурсы нужно получать через `your.package.R`, где `your.package` - пакет вашего приложения.

Comment: Так как правильно написать?

Comment: Удалите `import android.R` и в коде где `R` используется нажмите Alt-Enter и выберите правильный пакет.

Comment: Удаляю import android.R и все содержимое drawable видно без проблем, но появляется другая проблема: выдает ошибку когда я заполняю спиннер через адаптер:                 adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,
                    R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items3
                )

Answer (score 1):

Нужно корректно импортировать класс R вверху файла класса, где используются ресурсы приложения. Например, если пакет приложения называется com.example.myapp, нужно прописать:

```
import com.example.myapp.R;
```

Название пакета вашего приложения можно посмотреть в верхней части файла AndroidManifest.xml. В примере было бы следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.myapp">
```

Comment: С какой-то версии AGP атрибут `package` в манифесте объявлен устаревшим и заменён свойством `namespace` в gradle файле.

Comment: @woesss, в AGP 7.0 обьявлен deprecated, в APG 8.0 уже `namespace` обязателен.

Comment: пакет нашел добавил, все ок. но требуется или  import android.R или  import com.example.myapp.R где в первом случае не видно drawable, а во втором случае не работает код наполнения спиннера через адаптер:

Comment: adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items2)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему:
`import android.R` - оставил
`package com.example.название приложения` - уже было
доступ к drawable получил следующим образом:

`binding.ivExample.setImageResource(com.example.название_приложения.R.drawable.нужный_файл)`